# C++ - template vsprintf()?

Tags: c++, string, templates, printf

I'm extending the STL's basic_string class to add some useful functions like split, join, format, etc.

Is there a template c++ version of vsprintf() ? i.e template char type + variable args like `vsprintf<some_char_type>( some_buffer, some_format_string, ... )` ?

Also are there other types of chars than char and wchar_t used with strings ?

Thank you :)

Comment: I hope by extending you mean adding free functions that operate on it.

Comment: Yes, just extra methods.

Comment: What would you gain by having this? You still can’t do proper type-checking, because string operations are not really available at compile time.

Comment: I want this to be able to create a method format that would do the job of a classical sprintf, but taking into account the template parameter.

Comment: _"are there other types of chars"_ - yes. There's `char16_t` and `char32_t` used in `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` respectively. [This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) on the C++ String Library might help.

Comment: Okay thanks. How do you sprintf in these strings ? Using a string stream ?

Comment: Yes, you use a stringstream.

Comment: I would imagine `unsigned char` is used with strings as well.

Comment: I think you meant `sprintf`, not `vsprintf`... Anyway, consider using variadic templates and delegating to a templated conversion function function, so you can pass `std::string` and the lie directly.

Comment: I did mean vsprintf, thus the "...".

Comment: Have you considered the already written-and-debugged `boost::format` library instead of rolling your own?

Comment: @Virus721: `...` is used with `sprintf`, and `...` is _never_ used with `vsprintf`.  That's why we're confused.

Answer (score 0):

C++ inherits `vsprintf` from C. If you check the C89 standard `4.9.6.9` (for example) you learn that the one signature for that function is `int vsprintf(char *s, const char *format, va_list arg);`

Thus there are no corresponding versions of `vsprintf` that work with other character types.